# Secure Sync between remote computers

Tags: windows, live, synchronization, remote-backup

I've been trying to find a tool that will Sync between two remote computers securely and also run as a service so I don't have to stay logged in.

Windows Live sync seems to do the job although I've read it can't be run as a "service" reliably because it will occasionally log out of the service [http://www.dscoduc.com/post/2009/06/24/Dont-run-Live-Sync-as-a-Service.aspx]

Is there any alternatives out there or has anyone got the Live sync running as a service reliably?

Thanks
Chris

Comment: This question might be better answered at Server Fault or Super User... but I've used SyncBack before (http://www.2brightsparks.com/downloads.html) with good results.

Answer (score 1):

Try a Google search for "windows rsync" -- There are several alternatives